# Rhythmbox controls are missing from the SoundMenu

Tags: rhythmbox, indicator-sound

I Re-installed ubuntu two weeks ago and at the start I could control Rhythmbox from the sound menu, but now it disappeared and i don't know how to bring it back.

In "Sound prefernces...", in the "Applications" tab, rhythmbox is shown but i can only control it's volume.

For example in the start it was something like that (but for rhythmbox):
How it's supposed to be -

[image]

Comment: Help please.. =\

Comment: http://ubuntuguide.net/remove-rhythmbox-controls-from-ubuntu-12-04-sound-menu may help, maybe someone can form an answer around this.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have package `rhythmbox-plugins` installed. It contains MPRIS support which is vital for Sound Menu to work. After the package is installed, launch/restart Rhythmbox. Controls should appear in Sound Menu then.

You can find this package in Ubuntu Software Center:

[image: Install via the software center]

Or you can install it through terminal using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install rhythmbox-plugins
```

Comment: I have it and it still doesn't work =\

Comment: Can you see other players like Banshee in the sound menu?

Answer (score 0):

Rhythmbox only shows the controls when it is running, but I'm sure you knew that.

I would try to re-install Rhythmbox:

```
sudo apt-get remove rhythmbox
```

Followed by:

```
sudo apt-get install rhythmbox
```

Comment: Will it erase my music library in rhythmbox? because i worked on it a lot..

Comment: No, this will only reinstall the program, your personal settings will stay intact.

Comment: Did it solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a duplicate of question #68491. It appears that a Rhythmbox plugin ('MPRIS D-Bus interface') which is necessary for the player to communicate with the sound menu is not enabled by default on some 11.10 (and possibly earlier) installs. Kristal, please check to see if this is the case with yours. (Edit > Plugins from the Rhythmbox menu)